# e.preventdefault puts my Kendo Grid in an infinite loop

Tags: kendo-grid

I set a button .onclick to be false and I get the false value in my PHP program:

`$confirm = (isset($_GET['confirm']) ? $_GET['confirm'] : '');`

I set the variable confirm in my script to the PHP value. In the Kendo dataBinding I check if confirm is false, execute e.preventDefault(). While e.preventDefault() is executing, it appears that the Kendo Grid is trying to be rebuilt and gets in an infinite loop. Please advise.

````
   var sharedDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: 'PM_PipeMachineDelay.php?mode=DisplayAll',
                dataType: 'json'
            }
        },
        serverFiltering: true
        
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: sharedDataSource,
            dataBound: onDataBound,
            height: 700,
            sortable: true,
            resizeable: true,
            selectable: 'row',
            dataBinding: function(e) {
                if (confirm == "false") {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            },
            change: function(e) {
                var gview = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                var selectedItem = gview.dataItem(gview.select());
                window.location.href = 'PM_PipeMachineDelay.php?mode=Display' +
                    '&DSTNNO=' + selectedItem.DSTNNO +
                    '&DSTNID=' + selectedItem.DSTNID +
                    '&DPRDTE=' + selectedItem.DPRDTE +
                    '&DPRSHF=' + selectedItem.DPRSHF +
                    '&DDCATG=' + selectedItem.DDCATG +
                    '&DDTYPE=' + selectedItem.DDTYPE +
                    '&DSTTME=' + selectedItem.DSTTME +
                    '&DSPTME=' + selectedItem.DSPTME +
                    '&DDTIME=' + selectedItem.DDTIME +
                    '&DOPRNO=' + selectedItem.DOPRNO +
                    '&DINV=' + selectedItem.DINV +
                    '&OSTTME=' + selectedItem.DSTTME +
                    '&SecLevel=' + selectedItem.SecLevel;
                },

            filterable: {mode: "row"}, // this seems to make the complete row filterable
            /* remember this filter is for the client only; it doesn't go back to the server*/
            columns:[
                {hidden: true, field: "SecLevel"},
                {hidden: true, field: "OSTTME"},
                {title:"Station No", field:"DSTNNO", headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"Station ID", field:"DSTNID", headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"Station Description", field:"DSTNDSC", headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"Production Date", field:"DPRDTE",  headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"Production Shift", field:"DPRSHF",  headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"Delay Category", field:"DDCATG",  headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"Delay Type", field:"DDTYPE",  headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"Start Time", field:"DSTTME",  headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"Stop Time", field:"DSPTME",  headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"Delay Time", field:"DDTIME",  headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"Operator", field:"DOPRNO",  headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"Inventory #", field:"DINV",  headerFilter:"input"},
            ],
        });
    });```
````

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Conditionally bind the grid?

Comment: I was trying to store the action on a button if clicked when returning from one html to another. I resolved my issue by adding sessionStorage  on my Kendo Grid: